# Redirecting to component when using SEF

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, sef

Im trying to perform a redirect to a component's view

```
 <form role="form" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rouf&view=front');  ?>">
```

Because SEF is enabled im getting redirected at :

```
/index.php/component/rouf/?Itemid=0
```

and i get `The page isn't redirecting properly` error.

I never user SEF before but i would like to keep it, so how i perform the redirects at the views when SEF is enabled ?

Comment: Is `com_rouf` a custom component you built?

Comment: yes it is a custom component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do that and to accomplish more complicated tasks is to add a router file in `/components/com_rouf/router.php` with a class that will manage your custom routing.

Take a look at the `com_content/router.php` to have an idea and I suggest you to read this article: https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Anyway if the page you're going to redirect is a menu item, add the Itemid parameter to the link with the related menu item id, for a simple fix.